# How to find if a floating point is equal to an integer value in C++

Tags: c++, int

I am fairly inexperienced in C++ and I am designing a program that requires integers, but the values that need to become integers can also be floats, it depends on the user's choice. I have not found anything on how to do these functions. Basically my code looks like this:

```
float a;
cin >> a;
switch (a) {
case 1:
    break;
case 2:    
    break;
default:
    break;
}
```

And I need to check if it is an integer before the switch statement. Please help.

Comment: Maybe something like a == (int) a?

Comment: if(a == ((int) a)) works. But you should create template functions once, and call either the function<int> either the function <float> in the code.

Comment: This sounds like an odd requirement. The input value apparently serves multiple roles: as a selector, and as something else that isn't shown here. That's an awkward design; it would be better to separate the two activities, and use an integer value as the selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test it with:

```
if( a == (int)a ) { /*is integer*/ } else { /*not an integer*/ }
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is to use use floor() function and then compare:

```
if(floor(a) == a) { .... }
```

Comment: `std::floor` will only work when the actual value is slightly above an integer.  When it is slightly below, it would fall to the previous integer.

Comment: @ZacHowland : You are right, nevertheless, for the purpose of determining whether a float has no fractional part it is fine enough.

Comment: Not really.  `floor` will work for `5.0000000001`, but not for `4.999999999999995`.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you *close*

```
if (std::round(a) == a) { ... }
```

The floating point representation can be slightly above or slightly below the actual number, so a better solution would be:

```
double EPSILON = 0.0000000001;
if (std::abs(std::round(a) - a) < EPSILON) { ... }
```

Where you set `EPSILON` to the desired precision of your floating point number (e.g. if you want it precise to 8 decimal places, you would set `EPSILON = 0.00000001`).  This way, if the number is `4.999999999999934566` (very close to `5`), you would see it as `5`.  Additionally, if it is `5.000000000000000234`, you would still see it as `5`.

Comment: (std::round(a) == (int)a) is true for 2.25 and false for 2.75; unless a is really big, the absolute difference between round(a) and (int)a will be either 1.0 or 0.0. I think you meant `(std::abs(std::round(a) - a)) < EPSILON`

Comment: @rici:  Ah good catch.  I actually meant `std::round(a) == a`.  Thanks!